# Best way to create a query that uses tables from multiple schemas?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts-1

I'm working on a webapp served by Tomcat and Apache httpd the uses Struts 1.3.6 and Tomcat 6.

This app talks to Oracle and MySQL databases.  The Oracle DB has 14 different schemas and I have a select query that I want to put into an hbm.xml file that uses 8 tables from 3 of the Oracle schemas.  The intent is to dynamically add addition where clauses based on user input from the DynaActionForm.

I'm not allowed to build the select as an ad-hoc query and put it in the factory or action as shown in [Hibernate - Complex Query from multiple Tables to one object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197780/hibernate-complex-query-from-multiple-tables-to-one-object).

Is this possible?  If so, examples of this being done would be helpful.

Thanks

EDIT: I should have noted that the is a Hibernate session manager for the MySQL DB plus another for each of the Oracle schemas.

EDIT: The query in quesion...

```
select distinct
ca.addr_no as customer_number, decode(max(ctn.telephone_no),min(ctn.telephone_no),max(ctn.telephone_no),max(ctn.telephone_no)||', '||min(ctn.telephone_no)) as phone, ca.secondary_addressable_object||' '||ca.primary_addressable_object||' '||ca.street_name as street,
ca.primary_addressable_object, ca.street_name, ca.town_name as suburb, ca.postcode, ii.incident_ref, rd.report_ref, ii.description, ii.inc_category_id, ii.oz_name,
isl.look_up_description as status, ii.group_id, rlu.look_up_description as cause, to_char(ii.creation_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') as creation_date, nvl(cpa.link_reference,'VACANT') as nmi,
rc.report_id, ii.creation_date, ii.primary_ref, (ii.completed_date - ii.creation_date) as duration
from
tcs.inc_incident ii, pbr.rpt_details rd, enmac.look_up_list isl,
pbr.rpt_incident ri, pbr.rpt_reason rr, pbr.rpt_look_up rlu,
pbr.rpt_restoration_customers rc, tcs.cd_telephone_no ctn, tcs.cd_addresses ca,
tcs.cd_cust_property_assoc cpa, pbr.rpt_restoration_stages rs
where
ii.incident_id(+) = ri.incident_id||''
and ri.report_id||'' = rd.report_id(+)
and ii.status+0 = isl.look_up_reference(+)
and isl.look_up_name(+)||'' = 'Incident Status'
and ri.report_id||'' = rr.report_id(+)
and rr.cause_group||'' = rlu.look_up_code(+)
and rlu.look_up_field(+)||'' = 'CAUSE_GROUP'
and ri.report_id(+) = rc.report_id||''
and rc.pro_number(+) = ca.addr_no+0
and rc.stage_id||'' = rs.stage_id(+)
and rc.report_id||'' = rs.report_id(+)
and cpa.customer_no+0 = ctn.pro_number(+)
and cpa.customer_no(+) = ca.addr_no+0
and rs.status(+) = 0
```

optionally:

```
and ri.storm_flag(+) != 1 and rd.status(+) != -6
```

Continuing:

```
and ca.addr_no in (
```

With a while bunch more sub selects which vary depending on user input in the form.

I know that I'll need to convert from the old Oracle join style to the ANSI standard as part of this...

Comment: Can you please post the query? Also, are you expecting a list of entities to be returned as the result of the query, or is each row returned a mix of fields from different tables? Finally, if you are dynamically creating the query, it's probably best to use Hibernate criteria: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/

Comment: Edited again to show the SQL